# Do I need to handle org.springframework.validation.BindException if I am already handling org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

I am trying to write Control Advice and I want to keep similiar exception handling accross different services. My question is do I need to handle org.springframework.validation.BindException if I am already handling org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException?

I am not sure the difference between these 2 exceptions.

MethodArgumentNotValidException extends BindException.

It would be great if someone helps me to tell the scenario when BindException will be thrown and when MethodArgumentNotValidException will be thrown.

Comment: Not every `BindException` is a `MethodArgumentNotValidException`, so yes. When binding and not validation fails you will get another exception.